# Laravel 5 yield & section

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-5

I have the following structure:

```
- master.blade {

@yield('menu') // here I load the one and only menu I have

@yield('content') // here I load different pages

}

- menu.blade {
@extends('master')

@section('menu')
main menu
@stop
}

- other pages using the same format {
@extends('master')

@section('content')
here is the content
@stop
}
```

For some reason the menu is not loaded. Any ideas why? I try to load the menu and then page. It's simple stuff, but for some reason I don't see why it's not working.

Comment: if you're happy with my answer below, accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

1. use `@include('menu')` instead of `@yield('menu')` in `master.blade` layout.
2. remove `@extends`, `@section('menu')` and `@stop` from `menu.blade`

After these changes your code should look like:

**master.blade**

```blade
@include('menu')

@yield('content')
```

**menu.blade**

```blade
main menu
```

**other pages**

```blade
@extends('master')

@section('content')
    here is the content
@stop
```

Read more about templates: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates

btw, you can use `@endsection` instead of `@stop`, it's more readable as to me.

Answer (score 1):

The flow should be like this:

```
- master.blade {

@include('menu') // here I load the one and only menu I have

@yield('content') // here I load different pages

}

- menu.blade {

   Markup for the main menu

}

- other pages using the same format {
@extends('master')

@section('content')
   here is the content
@stop
}
```

Create simple menu file and include it in master template, yield is used for dynamic contents.